# Checkout básico - diferentes errores con tarjetas de prueba o reales

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Estoy utilizando Wordpress, Woocommerce y MercadoPago para Woocommerce, al intentar abonar con una tarjeta de crédito de prueba devuelve el error "el medio de pago no esta disponible", en caso de una tarjeta de crédito real devuelve el mismo error o "no se pudo procesar el pago", en el log no figura ningún error, y las tarjetas de crédito reales están activas y funcionales. ¿Hay algún tipo de configuración para el Checkout básico que de no ser correcta podría generar este error? La imagen a continuación muestra el error al intentar comprar con una de las tarjetas reales usadas (en la configuración no hay ninguna tarjeta excluida para comprar y todas las tarjetas que se utilizaron corresponden al mismo país de los datos de facturación y el sitio en si, Argentina).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es un error de codigo o de la API? si es de la API, no somos el soporte de mercado pago :(. si es de codigo podemos ayudarte si nos muestras el codigo..

Comment: No he escrito código ya que instalé el plugin de mercado pago para woocommerce en wordpress y lo configuré en el admin de wordpress, eso fue todo lo que hice. el código de la API debería estar incluido en el plugin, llegué acá a partir de un link de mercado pago que dice Foro de desarrolladores https://www.mercadopago.com.uy/developers/es/community/.

Comment: lee por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/324). No podemos hacer mucho por vos, pero tal vez tengas suerte.

Comment: Si interpreto de forma correcta la respuesta que me enviaste es un error de mercado pago entonces redirigir a los usuarios con dudas a este foro, muchas gracias de todas formas!

Comment: No es un error. En realidad nunca dejaron en claro la idea al redirigir a este sitio. (no somos un foro ;) ). Aca se responden preguntas sobre problemas de programacion, pero no sabemos nada de la API de ellos, y ellos no tienen a alguien que se ocupe particularmente de las preguntas sobre esos temas aca. Sin embargo sos bienvenido a seguir preguntando y contestando a tu gusto!. Lamento no poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Soy desarrollador y usuario activo de este "sitio para preguntar sobre problemas de programación" o como prefieras llamarlo, solo que me vi confundido por un link externo donde se invita a "consultar lo que quiera", y donde el titulo dice **Foro** de desarrolladores. En el link que dejé en el segundo comentario podrás verlo tu mismo. Gracias igualmente por tu aclaración.

Comment: Lo sabemos.. y hay mas preguntas en meta al respecto. sin embargo, nunca se hicieron cargo de esos links (figuran en los sitios de todos los paises) y ninguno se digno a aparecer por aca contestando esta clase de cosas.